# im getting the following error in mysql 'unexpected 'convert' (convert)

Tags: mysql

```
select ProductId,Product,sum(Counter) as Counter
from
V_OneSettlementForQuarterByProduct
where 
convert(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%M%D%Y'),'%M%D%Y'),convert(varchar(10),AuthDate,101),102) >= convert(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%M%D%Y'),'%M%D%Y'),convert(varchar(10),?,101),102) 
and convert(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%M%D%Y'),'%M%D%Y'),convert(varchar(10),AuthDate,101),102) <= convert(STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%M%D%Y'),'%M%D%Y'),convert(varchar(10),?,101),102) 
and ProductId =?
group by ProductId,Product
order by ProductId
```

Comment: These are a lot of conversions. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Bhagya, you seem trying to use TSQL syntax in MySQL. !!!???

Comment: All I can see is: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo,
For those who dont get the reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: hi thanks for the response.how to convert the string to date in mysql?@juergen

Comment: hey ... thanks..how to make the the above query to run in mysql ? it contains errors and i know lot of conversions needs to be done but not getting what exactly  i need to do...@ Ravinder